# ¿Cómo escribir un archivo CSV con un flujo de información continua?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, csv, dataframe

estoy descargando información del API de Kraken y quiero crear una base de datos en formato CSV, la información se descarga por minuto, la convierto en DataFrame, al usar el write de CSV no me escribe la demás información que se esta descargando, les dejo el código:

```
import time, json, request
import pandas as pd
import csv

    def preciocerradas():
            krakenTick = 
            
requests.post('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker',data=json.dumps({"pair":"XETHZUSD"}),
            headers={"content-type":"application/json"})
        return krakenTick.json()['result']['XETHZUSD']['c'][0]
    
        while True:
            Precio = float(preciocerradas())
            time.sleep(1) # 120 equals two minutes, you can ping it every second by putting a 1 in here
            Data = {'Precio1': [Precio]}
            df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['Precio1'])
            df.to_csv('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/trading BTC/ROBOTS DE INVERSIÓN CON PYTHON/SECCION 1. 
            PYTHON/ETH.csv')
            csvwriter = csv.writer(open('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/trading BTC/ROBOTS DE INVERSIÓN CON P 
            PYTHON/SECCION 
            1. PYTHON/ETH.csv', 'wb'))    
            csvwriter.writerow(Data, columns = ['Precio1'])
```

Intentando lo anterior, me surge el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: writerow() takes no keyword arguments
```

Realmente, lo que quiero hacer es crear una base de datos con información que es continua, y que en el momento que detenga el algoritmo se escriba y guarde toda la información.

Comment: Hola Eduardo!  tu código tiene problemas de identación, la variable `krakenTick` está mal definida y no se  saben las **librerías que estás usando** porque faltan las importaciones. Puedes corregir/completar estas partes por favor? Así será más fácil ayudarte!

Comment: Hola Rubiales, ya lo modifique.